# Send multiple images telegram bot api

Tags: php, telegram, telegram-bot

Is it possible to send **multiple images in 1 message** using telegram bot api, **php**? I know about method `sendPhoto()`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

there is an API called [sendMediaGroup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup) and one of the php libraries which has implemented it is [this](https://github.com/php-telegram-bot/core).

Comment: Should be noted, that `reply_markup` and, in my case, specifically `parse_mode` are unavailable with this approach

Comment: Hi @MikeK you can use parse_mode easily, you just need to use it in the correct place, note that it must be next to the caption, which consequently must generate the dictionary here: https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58895281/11462274)