# How to send telegram mediaGroup with caption/text

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I'm currently using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot) and basically what I want to achieve with it is to send telegram messages like this:

[image: telegram post with 3 photos and caption]

So the message consists of 2+ photos/videos with text message underneath.

What I've already tried:

1. sending message with [send_message](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_message) method, and including photo URLs, **but it only shows 1 picture which is under the text**
2. sending media group using [send_media_group](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_media_group), **but this method has no `caption` parameter as [send_photo](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.bot.html#telegram.Bot.send_photo).**

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You should use [sendMediaGroup](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#sendmediagroup), where you can specify `media` field with an array of [photo](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto)/[video](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediavideo) objects but the trick is to set `caption` property only **for the first element of an array**. In this case telegram will show that caption below the media content.

If you'll specify captions for more than one element telegram will show them only when you click on photo preview for each photo separately.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it definitely works! But why it's not mentioned anywhere??

Answer (score 9):

`send_media_group` works but the caption has to be added when creating the `media_group` and to the first image only. Let's say we have three images `img0.png`, `img1.png` and `img2.png`, we add them to the `media_group` using `InputMediaPhoto` with the parameter `caption` equal to the text we want to send only for the first image, otherwise we set `caption` equal to `''`.

```
import telegram
from telegram import InputMediaPhoto

TOKEN = '' # token to access the HTTP API of your bot created with @BotFather
CHANNEL_ID = '' # id of your channel, for example @durov
bot = telegram.Bot(token = TOKEN)
media_group = []
text = 'some caption for album'
for num in range(3):
    media_group.append(InputMediaPhoto(open('img%d.png' % num, 'rb'), 
                                       caption = text if num == 0 else ''))
bot.send_media_group(chat_id = CHANNEL_ID, media = media_group)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, your example code works

Answer (score 2):

Here is a vanilla Python implementation using `requests`:

```py
SEND_MEDIA_GROUP = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMediaGroup'

def send_media_group(chat_id, images, caption=None, reply_to_message_id=None):
        """
        Use this method to send an album of photos. On success, an array of Messages that were sent is returned.
        :param chat_id: chat id
        :param images: list of PIL images to send
        :param caption: caption of image
        :param reply_to_message_id: If the message is a reply, ID of the original message
        :return: response with the sent message
        """
        files = {}
        media = []
        for i, img in enumerate(images):
            with BytesIO() as output:
                img.save(output, format='PNG')
                output.seek(0)
                name = f'photo{i}'
                files[name] = output.read()
                # a list of InputMediaPhoto. attach refers to the name of the file in the files dict
                media.append(dict(type='photo', media=f'attach://{name}'))
        media[0]['caption'] = caption
        return requests.post(SEND_MEDIA_GROUP, data={'chat_id': chat_id, 'media': json.dumps(media), 'reply_to_message_id': reply_to_message_id }, files=files)
```