# How to send a message in Telegram using SendMediaGroup with Text Message in C#?

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

I want to send an Album with a text message and this is my code in C#:

```
    private void CInPrbdg_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
      List<FileStream> streams = new List<FileStream>
        {
            System.IO.File.OpenRead(imgpath1),
            System.IO.File.OpenRead(imgpath2),
        };

        List<InputMediaPhoto> media = new List<InputMediaPhoto>();

        foreach(var stream in streams)
        {
            media.Add(new InputMediaPhoto(new InputMedia(stream, stream.Name)) 
            {
                Caption = txt1,
                ParseMode = ParseMode.Markdown
            });
        }

        await Vbot.SendMediaGroupAsync(media, chatid);
    }
```

This code shows that the caption will only show like this: [Image with Caption in Telegram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Aiuo.png) but i want it to be like this: [Album with Text Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3mzSx.png). Thank you.

[image: Current]
[image: Expected]

Comment: Which library do you use?

Comment: You need to add Caption only First Photo. Full answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893142/how-to-send-telegram-mediagroup-with-caption-text