# Does Telegram API have opportunity to send photo album with text?

Tags: telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I see it can send a single photo with text and an album without text. But I need to send album and text in one message. Is it possible?

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893142/how-to-send-telegram-mediagroup-with-caption-text

Answer (score 0):

Surely you can!

https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto

Your message with the album should contain an array of inputMediaPhoto (link above). And if you set caption for any of the inputMediaPhoto, it will display in the message!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.